# Como juntar duas variáveis?

Tags: php

Tenho duas variáveis assim

```html
$links = "link1
link2
link3
link4";

$titulo = "titulo1
titulo2
titulo3
titulo4";
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a juntar as duas e ficar desse jeito:

```html
<a href="link1">Titulo1</a>
<a href="link2">Titulo2</a>
<a href="link3">Titulo3</a>
<a href="link4">Titulo4</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quebre as duas variáveis em array pela quebra de linha `\n` e faça a iteração em uma pegando o valor da outra pelo índice:

```
<?php
$links = "link1
link2
link3
link4";

$titulo = "titulo1
titulo2
titulo3
titulo4";

$links_array = explode("\n", $links);
$titulo_array = explode("\n", $titulo);

foreach($links_array as $indice=>$link){
   echo '<a href="'. $link .'">'. $titulo_array[$indice] .'</a>';
}
?>
```

O resultado será o HTML:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: com essa função, se no $links tiver um espaço em branco em baixo do ultimo valor link4, aparece um <a href></a> em branco no echo, será que tem como remover e evitar isso com está função?

Comment: Vc pode remover a última quebra de linha com preg_replace: `$links_array = explode("\n", preg_replace('/\n$/', '', $links));`

Comment: obrigado, funcionou... mas sabe se por exemplo, tiver um espaço entre link1 e link2, vai ficar um <a href></a> entre eles, sabe se tinha como excluir se tivesse espaços entre os links?